# Cassandra design approach for my sample use case

Tags: cassandra

Im learning cassandra from past few days. Tried to create a data model for the following use case..

```
"Each Zipcode in US has a list of stores sorted based on a defined rank"
"Each store/warehouse has millions of SKUs and the inventory is tracked"
"If I search using a zipcode and SKU, it should return the best possible 100 stores 
with inventory, based on the rank"

Assume store count is 1000+ and sku count is in millions
```

Design tried

```
One table with 
ZipCode
Rank
StoreID
primary key (ZipCode, Rank)

Another table with

Sku
Store
Inventory
Primary Key (Sku, Store)
```

> Now, if I want to search top 100 stores for each ZipCode, SKU
>   combination..
>
> I have to search in table 1 for the top 100 stores and
>   then pull inventory of each store from the second table.
>
> *Since the SKU count is in millions and store count is in 1000+, m not
>   sure if we can store all this in one table and have zipcode_sku as row
>   key and stores and inventory stored as wide row sorted by rank*
>
> **Am I thinking right? What could be other possible data models for this use case?**

---

UPDATE: Data Loader Code (as mentioned in below comments)

```
println "Loading data started.."
        (1..1000000).each { // SKUs
            sku = it.toString()
            (1..42000).each { // Zip Codes
                zipcode = it.toString().padLeft(5,"0")
                (1..1500).each { // Stores
                    store = it.toString()
                    int inventory = Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 10000) + 1
                    session.execute("INSERT INTO ritz.rankedStoreByZipcodeAndSku(sku, zipcode, store, store_rank, inventory) " +
                            "VALUES('$sku','$zipcode','$store',$it,$inventory);")
                }
            }
        }
        println "Data Loaded"
```

Comment: No idea why this is down voted. Cassandra is open source and in all webinars there is a big talk about developer community helping others step up. This seems to be the only forum where doubts can be raised on cassandra. There is a good amount of research, coding, experimenting went on before I post this question. I tried one table approach.. seeing the volume of data, I thought there is an alternate way and this question was posted. Not sure whats the criteria to ask a question in this forum :(

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is a Columnar database, so you can have wide rows that you usually want to represent each kind of query you want to make.  In this case

```
CREATE TABLE storeByZipcodeAndSku (
  sku text,
  zipcode int,
  store text,
  store_rank int,
  inventory int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((sku, zipcode), store)
);
```

This way the row key is sku + zipcode so its a very fast lookup and you can store up to 2 billion stores in it.  When you update your inventory also update this table.  To get the top 100 you just pull down all of them and sort (1000's is not many) but if this operation is super common and you need it faster you can instead use

```
CREATE TABLE rankedStoreByZipcodeAndSku (
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY ((sku, zipcode), store_rank)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (store_rank ASC);
```

to have it sorted for you automatically and you just grab the top 100.  Then when you update it you will want to use the lightweight transactions to move things around atomically.

Comment: Thanks Chris.. I wrote a sample code and loaded the data in the table. The sample I used had 100 SKUs, 100 ZipCodes and 200 stores. It created 2,000,000 rows. Search is extremely fast and results were back in <=1 millis for any combination I tried with a bot.. My question is if I go back to my original use case of 2mil SKUs X 42k Zips X 2k stores, the number of rows will be humongous, right? Or split this into multiple tables for based on some zip code range segregation (like table 1 for zip 1-1000 and so on) Or SKU Types (based on SKU class). Excuse if I dont make much sense. Trying to...

Comment: ..understand how experts approach these use cases.

Comment: Correction .. search average for 1000 random calls was 1.7 mills and max was 6 mils.

Comment: The number of partitions will be the number of skus * zips.  Partitions are safe to have a ton of, they will scale linearly with the number of nodes.  If it gets to be to many can just add nodes to fix the problems.  The maximum rows in a partition would really be the number of stores in storeByZipcodeAndSku or the number of ranks in rankedStoreByZipcodeAndSku although empirically it wont be anywhere near that bad.  That is where your 2 billion limit is, in the number of stores or ranks.

Comment: Chris, Just want to make sure I understood -  the amount of partitions (sku*zip), which I see as "rows" in "table" is 1,000,000 X 42,000 = 42,000,000,000 (42 billion). Each of these keys (or rows) will be 1500 (stores) wide. It will take a hell lot of time to insert this data in the beginning, right? I wrote a simple data loader and it took for ever to even complete 1 sku. May be thats not the right way to insert or even to gauge (one VM in my laptop). But m still looking at these volumes and going "huh".. (loader code updated in the question)

Comment: May want to try loading it initially with: http://planetcassandra.org/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get a list of StoreID's from the first table based on ZipCode, and a list of StoreID's from the second table based on Sku, and then do a join.  Since Cassandra is a simple key value store, it doesn't do join's.  So you would have to either write code in your client to do the two queries and manually do the join, or connect Cassandra to spark which has a join function.

As you say, trying to denormalize the two tables into one table so that you could do this as one query might result in a very large and difficult to maintain table.  If this is the only query pattern you will have, then that might be worth it, but if this is a general inventory system with a lot of different query patterns, then it might be too inflexible.

The other option would be to use an RDBMS instead of Cassandra, and then joins are super easy.